# Parrot Mambo Drone Won't Fly Forward Using pyparrot

Tags: python, python-3.5, ar.drone

My Parrot Mambo won't drive forwards or backwards or any direction. It will only take off, flip, and land.

I connect to it's wifi connection and try to run the demoDirectFlight.py as part of the pyparrot module, and it will only go up, flip, and land again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to keep the controller turned off when connecting over wifi and running the script. I guess the controller overrides any control over everything except taking off, landing, and flipping.